# T.test R program

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a t.test for a lot of data sets and I want to them to be contained in a single ouput
So far I'm doing a t.test similar to this

```
test1=t.test(dat$velocity,x[[1]][[2]])
test2=t.test(dat$velocity,x[[2]][[2]])
test3=t.test(dat$velocity,x[[3]][[2]])
```

Comment: You already asked this question. Instead of posting a *new* question, if your original question has not been satisfactorily answered, *edit* that question to update it with further information instead of posting a new question.

Comment: Also, please do read Stackoverflow's [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and its [frequently asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) page for an overview on how to use the site more effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
tests <- lapply(1:length(x), function(i) t.test(dat$velocity,x[[i]][[2]]))
```

`tests` is a list `list` of the length `length(x)`. You can access each t-test result with `tests[[1]]`.

Comment: Thanks...it worked well...I also figured out how to get just the p value